# How to add custom tab to facebook profile

Tags: facebook

I need to add custom tab to my facebook profile.

I know that, we can use static FBML application to create the customize tab. But this fbml application is going to add tab to our page(created by us) not profile.

My Goal is:

Need to create customize tab in facebook profile.

In side tab , we should show some button. i need to load my webpage in iframe when some one clicks on that button.

When some one else visit the my profile, the newly created tab should visible to him. So that my profile visitors able to see my website.

Thanks

Comment: Can you find a way to add custom tab to your facebook personal profile (not a page)? Some Facebook apps like Pinterest, Runtastic, Yelp, Instagram, Foursquare, Codecademy, have custom sections (in "MORE" of Drop-Down control of Users' Personal Profile) and post there text,pictures, videos.

Answer (score 1):

Only Facebook Pages (not profiles) currently support tabs.